# Template reference argument deduction failure in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constants, c++14

Why following code doesn't compile in C++14 compiler? If I use

```
const int i = 10;
int n = fun(i);
```

The compiler gives an error.

But, If I use

```
int n = fun(10);
```

instead of above statements, it's working fine.

**Example:**

```
template<typename T>
int fun(const T&&)
{
    cout<<"fun"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
 // int i = 10;         // Not work
    const int i = 10;   // Not work
    int n = fun(i);  
 // int n = fun(10);    // Working fine
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `const` here?

Comment: Constant rvalue references are almost always an error. If you can't give a detailed explanation about why it's needed in a specific case, then don't use it.

Comment: use std::move( i ); in the utilities header file. Be aware that moving will invalidate what was moved. Also you shouldn't move from a const as moving is doing something to it. Scott Meyers has a great talk on type deduction on YouTube (and a chapter in Effective Modern C++), sounds like you'd benefit from watching it.

Comment: @Treebeard - `std::move` doesn't invalidate or move anything. It's a simple cast. It's what the type does when accepting such a reference that matters.

Comment: OK, more clarification in what I meant, The object still exists after moving but you cannot guarantee it's state (e.g. contents might be empty), however it's still valid in that it can be destructed or reassigned it.

Comment: @Treebeard - No even that is globally true. `std::move` on it's own does nothing to change any object state.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It fails because adding the const prevents it from being a forwarding reference. It becomes a regular reference to a const rvalue:

[[temp.deduct.call/3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#call-3)

> ... A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a **cv-unqualified**
>   template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a
>   class template (during class template argument deduction
>   ([over.match.class.deduct])). ...

And you pass it an lvalue. It fails the match.

Answer (score 2):

This here

```
int fun(const T&&)
```

means you need to give as parameter a `rVal`

so

```
const int i = 10;
```

is not making `i` a candidate to be a `rVal` (because you can get the address of i)